# max number of TCP socket objects can be stored in an array in node.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I am working on TCP Socket based a client-server application and using array to keep all socket connections at server (using node.js). As ~65k TCP socket can be handled by a server but wanted to get more info on following,

1. How much socket connection can be stored in an array.
2. Is storing socket object in an array correct approach or another better approach is available
3. any hint on monitoring and keeping client connection live

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: You're wrong already. Many more than 65k sockets can be handled by a TCP server. You don't normally need an array of them however.

Comment: Thanks. If don't need array then how server could push or send a message to a socket, which has connected earlier.

Comment: There are other data structures besides arrays. Most people create objects with handlers. You don't need a collection of all your clients at all.

Comment: Still I am not able to identify your hint. Could you pls share little more details or link around the other data structure or handler. That will help me. Thanks.

Comment: @EJP I am still struggling to find proper solution to keep sockects. It would be helpful to me if you could share little more information about the "create objects with handler" as you suggested. I can see you are a valued person in the forum and your suggestion will surely help me.

Comment: @EJP I got it at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20847139/3574669. Hope same you have hinted.